# Resizable sidenav using angular Material(7) & angular 7

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular6, angular7, angular-material-6

**My requirement is resizable/customizable sidenav, here is angular js demo**

```
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Reklino/pen/raRaXq)
```

I want to implement exact same thing using Angular(Version 7) & Angular Material(Version 7). In angular material 7 sidenav open/close/toggle functionality present [material sidenav doc](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview) but resizable functionality not there.

Guys, can you guide me how to achieve this functionality? Pls share any kind reference/npm library.
I would appreciate the help, Many thanks!